# Is there a way to cut a layer according to the another, all at once in Premiere?

Tags: premiere

I'm using Adobe Premiere CS6, and I have a bunch of layers that I cut hundreds of times, but I had the audio track on lock by accident. Is there a way I can just have that layer cut the same as the others all at once and now have to cut them one by one?